# How to change the owneship of default.conf file in code::blocks editor in ubuntu?

Tags: codeblocks

I just started using `code::blocks` editor and found that its default font size is smaller to me.Whenever I open it I have to manually resize the font by `settings -> editor -> choose`. I'm finding a way to make my customised settings as default.

[image]

I have searched about it all over the internet but didn't find a solution. I somewhere read that basic settings are stored in a file named `default.conf` which is only readable and only `root` has permission to edit it. How can I change its permission to make it writeable or some other way .So, can somebody please help me how can I make my customized settings as default. I'm in desperate need.

Comment: This belongs on Ask Ubuntu at https://askubuntu.com

Comment: 3 words: switch to root.

Comment: @zixuan How?Can you tell me the procedure. It will be a great help from you.

Comment: First, access the terminal. Then do `sudo -i`. Next, navigate `default.conf` and change that easily.